# Learning about GKE Kubernetes Ingress auto generated manifests

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I notice that when I create an Ingress on GKE several annotations are automatically generated thus:

annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s-be-30266--edf23f6631e3474e":"HEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s-fw-default-nginx-ingress--edf23f6631e3474e
    ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s-tp-default-nginx-ingress--edf23f6631e3474e
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-default-nginx-ingress--edf23f6631e3474e

Is there any way these annotations can be viewed, as this would help me further understand better. TIA

Shaun

Comment: What did you mean by `Is there any way these annotations can be viewed` because you have already some how viewed that, am I right? maybe you want to know how they were attach or how to export it as YAML or what?

Comment: I would like to know how to export them to YAML. TIA

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use `get` and `-o yaml`
For example:

`kubectl get deployment myapp-deployment -o yaml`

result in terminal will be YAML with whole configuration of deployment `myapp-deployment`
More useful command you can find in official [doc page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)